Does time always dilate?
Consider an immobilised system O and a moving with speed v relative to O system O’.
By (x,t) we denote the spacetime coordinates of a point.
For two events A,B happening in O consider the following separate scenarios:
1)First scenario, A is A(0,0) and B is B(0,t),

Second scenario A is A(0,0) and B is (vt, t).

In the first scenario, in O’ the two events differ by Dt = gamma*t, while in the second scenario the two events differ by t/gamma. So, does time always dilate?

In reality time does not dilate. This is only an impression we get if we measure the time in another system using the light speed. But an impression is not the reality.

@Peter according to me time dilation is the difference in magnitude of time measured by two different observers

@Peter time does dilate, it has been experimentally verified by measuring the flight time of atmospheric high-energy particles and comparing it to their usual lifetime in their rest frame.

@paulina I have read a lot of critical papers about the relativity theories (of course it is harder to find them than to find mainstream papers) , therefore I know the errors usually made. That time passes in another system different is a myth , nothing else.

any answer to my question? Peter, I am not sure if time dilation is well-defined, and with the example given in this post I am trying to demonstrate two possible, though contradictory, interpretations of time dilation.

@Peter I am sure there are many "papers" which are critical of the special theory of relativity. There are also "papers" which claim to have proven Fermat's last theorem using nothing but high school algebra. Of course everyone measures time to pass at the same speed in their own rest frame, the point is that you measure different passages of time in inertial frames which are related to your own by a Lorentz boost. Incidentially, this is also the answer to the original question: OP simply got the spacetime geometry entirely wrong. I have voted to migrate this to physics.SE, where it belongs.

@paulina what do you mean by "OP simply got the spacetime geometry entirely wrong"? can you elaborate on this?

"I have voted to migrate this to physics.SE, where it belongs." Here , I agree.

In relativity it is important to remember that there are two distinct concepts of time. Coordinate time, $t$, is the time in some reference frame, while proper time, $\tau$, is the time measured by some specific clock. The two are related by the spacetime interval in an inertial frame: $$c^2 d\tau^2=c^2 dt^2 - dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$ which can be solved to obtain $$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
This quantity is always less than or equal to $1$, with equality only when $v=0$. So a clock always has a proper time that runs slowly with respect to coordinate time in an inertial frame where it is moving.

In the first example the two events take take place at the same position as measured by the observer $O$. This is why the time difference between them is greater as measured by observer $O'$ so time dilation occurs.
On the other hand, in the second example, the events take place at the same place in the reference frame $O'$: $x=vt$ so $x'=\gamma(x-vt)=0$. In this case time dilation occurs again, but now the observer which measures a longer time will be $O$.
In general time dilation can be described as follows: when two events happen at the same position in space in one reference frame, the difference between their time coordinates will be greater in a reference frame which is moving with respect to the first.
